# Go f(...) versus : f(go func(){...}())

Tags: go, closures, goroutine

Am I correct to assume that with the Go language, these two formulations are always equivalent ?

```
func f() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

```
go f()
```

and

```
func f() {
   go func(){
     // do stuff
   }()
)
```

Comment: Its is now (I corrected it)

Comment: The statements as written have the same result.  The first is often preferred because the caller is in control of concurrency.

Comment: However, if f() must always be called as a separate process, then the second formulation automates that task.

Comment: It's often the case that concurrency may not always be needed, or it may be more convenient to structure the synchronization differently depending on the context. The convention is usually to allow the caller to decide when the directly called function needs to be concurrent, and only dispatch goroutines as part of the implementation details as required.

Comment: The first formulation allows the caller to bracket `// do stuff` with other code, wait for `// do stuff` to complete, etc..  The second formulation may be the right choice for your actual problem, but it is not the right choice in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The question was basically answered in the comments, but although in the simple case both examples do the same thing, one may be preferred over the other depending on what the actual goal is.

One that the comments mention is allowing the user of your code to decide on concurrency vs you (the writer) deciding. I think this rule of thumb is generally preferred especially for people writing packages for others to use (even if perhaps the others are in your own team). I've also seen this rule of thumb espoused elsewhere on "the internet", and I think arose because in the early days of Go, people were using (and abusing) concurrency features just because they were available. For example, returning a channel from which you'd receive a value instead of just returning the value.

Another difference is that in the top example, `f()` may not be able to close on variables that you might want accessible when run as a goroutine--you'd have to pass everything into `f()` as a parameter. In the second example the anonymous function in `go func() {...}` could close over something in `f()`.

One example where I prefer the second style is starting servers. For example:

```golang
func (app *Application) start() {
    if app.HttpsServer != nil {
        go func() {
            err := app.HttpsServer.ListenAndServeTLS(
                app.Config.TLSCertificateFile,
                app.Config.TLSKeyFile)
            if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
                // unexpected error
                log.Printf(log.Critical, "error with https server: %s", err)
            }
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        err := app.HttpServer.ListenAndServe()
        if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            // unexpected error
            log.Printf(log.Critical, "error with http server: %s", err)
        }
    }()
}
```

Here the intention is that `Application` is configured and controlled in `main()`, the servers (one on https, one on http) are started and program flow returns to `main()`. In my specific case, `main()` waits for a signal from the OS then shuts down the servers and exits. Both goroutines close over `app` and have access to the data it contains. Is this "good" or "bad"...who knows, but it works well for me.

So essentially... "It depends".

Comment: Please note : I never asked if there was a good formulation or a bad one. I merely wanted to ask if they are always equivalent.

Comment: If you use it in an equivalent manner, they should be essentially equivalent. But that's a useless answer, so I gave examples of why you might choose one way or another.